# Why does deepcopy change values of numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, scipy, copy, ode

I am having a problem in which values in a Numpy array change after copying it with copy.deepcopy or numpy.copy, in fact, I get different values if I just print the array first before copying it.

I am using Python 3.5, Numpy 1.11.1, Scipy 0.18.0

My starting array is contained in a list of tuples; each tuple is pair: a float (a time point) and a numpy array (the solution of an ODE at that time point), e.g.:

```
[(0.0, array([ 0.,  ...  0.])), ...
 (3.0, array([ 0.,  ...  0.]))]
```

In this case, I want the array for the last time point.

When I call the following:

```
tandy = c1.IntegrateColony(3)
ylast = copy.deepcopy(tandy[-1][1])
print(ylast)
```

I get something that makes sense for the system I'm trying to simulate:

```
[7.14923891e-07   7.14923891e-07 ... 8.26478813e-01   8.85589634e-01]
```

However, with the following:

```
tandy = c1.IntegrateColony(3)
print(tandy[-1][1])
ylast = copy.deepcopy(tandy[-1][1])
print(ylast)
```

I get all zeros:

```
[0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
[ 0.  0.  ...  0.  0.]
```

I should add, with larger systems and different parameters, displaying tandy[k][1] (either with print() or just by calling it in the command line) shows all non-zero values that are all very close to zero, i.e. <1e-70, but that's still not sensible for the system.

With:

```
tandy = c1.IntegrateColony(3)
ylast = np.copy(tandy[-1][1])
print(ylast)
```

I get sensible output again:

```
[7.14923891e-07   7.14923891e-07 ... 8.26478813e-01   8.85589634e-01]
```

The function that generates 'tandy' is the following (edited for clarity), which uses scipy.integrate.ode, and the set_solout method to get the solution at intermediate time points:

```
def IntegrateColony(self, tmax=1):
    # I edited out initialization of dCdt & first_step for clarity.
    y = ode(dCdt)
    y.set_integrator('dopri5', first_step=dt0, nsteps=2000)
    sol = []
    def solout(tcurrent, ytcurrent):
        sol.append((tcurrent, ytcurrent))

    y.set_solout(solout)
    y.set_initial_value(y=C0, t=0)
    yfinal = y.integrate(tmax)

    return sol
```

Although I could get the last time point by returning yfinal, I'd like to get the whole time course once I figure out why it's behaving the way it is.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Mickey

---

Edit:
If I print all of sol (`print(tandy)` or `print(IntegrateColony...`), it comes out as shown above (with the values in the arrays as 0), i.e.:

```
[(0.0, array([ 0.,  ...  0.])), ...
 (3.0, array([ 0.,  ...  0.]))]
```

However, if I copy it with (`y = copy.deepcopy(tandy); print(y)`), the arrays take on values between 1e-7 and 1e+1.

If I do `print(tandy[-1][1])` twice in a row, they're filled with zeros, but the format changes (from `0.0000` to `0.`).

One other feature I noticed while following the suggestions in LutzL's and hpaulj's comments: if I run `tandy = c1.IntegrateColony(3)` in the console (running Spyder), the arrays are filled with zeros in the variable explorer. However, if I run the following in the console:

```
tandy = c1.IntegrateColony(3); ylast=copy.deepcopy(tandy)
```

Both the arrays in tandy and in ylast are filled with values in the range I would expect, and `print(tandy[-1][1])` now gives:

```
[7.14923891e-07   7.14923891e-07 ... 8.26478813e-01   8.85589634e-01]
```

Even if I find a solution that stops this behavior, I'd appreciate anyone's insight about what's going on so I don't make the same mistakes again.

Thanks!

---

Edit:
Here's a simple case that gives this behavior:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode


def testODEint(tmax=1):
    C0 = np.ones((3,))
    # C0 = 1  # This seems to behave the same

    def dCdt_simpleinputs(t, C):
        return C

    y = ode(dCdt_simpleinputs)

    y.set_integrator('dopri5')
    sol = []

    def solout(tcurrent, ytcurrent):
        sol.append((tcurrent, ytcurrent))  # Behaves oddly
        # sol.append((tcurrent, ytcurrent.copy()))  # LutzL's idea: Works

    y.set_solout(solout)
    y.set_initial_value(y=C0, t=0)
    yfinal = y.integrate(tmax)

    return sol

tandy = testODEint(1)
ylast = np.copy(tandy[-1][1])
print(ylast)  # Expect same values as tandy[-1][1] below

tandy = testODEint(1)
tandy[-1][1]
print(tandy[-1][1])  # Expect same values as ylast above
```

When I run this, I get the following output for `ylast` and `tandy[-1][1]`:

```
[ 2.71828196  2.71828196  2.71828196]
[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
```

The code I was working on when I ran into this problem is an embarrassing mess, but if you want to take a look, an old version is here: https://github.com/mvondassow/BryozoanModel2

Comment: If you print all of sol, do the rows change or is all the same? You might have to use `sol.append((tcurrent, ytcurrent.copy()))` to avoid storing always the same pointer to the state vector of the integrator.

Comment: Don't bother with `deepcopy` when you know the object is an array.  `x.copy()` is sufficient.  But I think there's something funny about `tandy`.  It isn't just a list of independent values.  What happens when you do `print(tandy[-1][1])` twice in a row?

Comment: I'll give that a try, LutzL.

Comment: Thank you, LutzL and hpaulj, for your suggestions! At least for a few quick tests, LutzL's suggestion about using `ytcurrent.copy()` when appending to sol seems to fix the strange behavior. However, I'd love to know why calling just `tandy` or `print(tandy)` vs `copy.deepcopy(tandy)` or `numpy.copy(tandy)` affects the values it's pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

The details of why this is happening are tied to how `ytcurrent` is handled in `integrate`.  But there are various contexts in Python where all values of a list end up the same - contrary to expectations.

For example:

```
In [159]: x
Out[159]: [0, 1, 2]
In [160]: x=[]
In [161]: y=np.array([1,2,3])
In [162]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     y += i
     ...:     x.append(y)
In [163]: x
Out[163]: [array([4, 5, 6]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([4, 5, 6])]
```

All elements of `x` have the same value - because they all are pointers to the same `y`, and thus show its final value.

but if I copy `y` before appending it to the list, I see the changes.

```
In [164]: x=[]
In [165]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     y += i
     ...:     x.append(y.copy())
In [166]: x
Out[166]: [array([4, 5, 6]), array([5, 6, 7]), array([7, 8, 9])]
In [167]:
```

Now that does not explain why the `print` statement changes the values.  But that whole `solout` callback mechanism is a bit obscure.  I wonder if there are any warnings in `scipy` about pitfalls in defining such a callback?

Comment: Thanks hpaulj. I couldn't find any discussion of pitfalls about `solout`. The case you describe is familiar (though I _still_ get tripped up by it often enough!), but doesn't seem to explain the behavior I'm seeing. Also, just calling `tandy[-1][1]` (e.g. in the console) makes it differ from `numpy.copy()`). `copy.deepcopy(somearray)` & `numpy.copy(somearray)` both call numpy's `array(somearray)` but I got lost tracing the numpy maze further... Maybe `array(somearray)` calls values in a different way?

Comment: If you give us a complete copy-n-paste example, I could run it and examine the `tandy` object myself.  I would also try variations, like one that just stores the current value, or one that prints a value at each iteration.

Comment: I added a simple example to my original question that does what I've been running into. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: In each `solout` call, `ytcurrent` has a new `id`, but it shares the data buffer (along with `yfinal`).  They are all `views` of the same thing. So if you want `ytcurrent` value for each iteration (as opposed to just the final one), you have to use the `copy` in `solout`.  I still haven't figured out why an 'unprotected' print resets the values.

Comment: I've concluded that this resetting is caused by an internal numpy bug; it's nothing to do with misuse in your code.  I suppose we could search for or file a bug report.  But regardless of whether it is fixed or not, the `copy()` in `solout` is the correct usage.

Comment: Is it possible that Python is garbage collecting `yfinal` and therefore getting rid of what `ytcurrent` is pointing to? Perhaps `print` (or calling) has nothing to do with it. I just noticed that if I just run line by line (`tandy = ...` then `ylast = ...`) the values in the `ytcurrent` arrays in `tandy` all go to zero; if I both return and store `yfinal`, the values of `tandy` stick around, but -- something I managed to miss all this time -- all `ytcurrent` arrays in `tandy` are identical to `yfinal`. So, I think your answer was spot on, but with one added wrinkle. What do you think?

Comment: When I move the `solout` definition outside the `testODEint` code, I can't reproduce this 'go to zero' behavior.  Or a simpler change in your function - return `yfinal` along with `sol`.

Comment: I still wish I understood the reason for the behavior, but thank you for all your help.